# How to draw a down arrow inside a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a \downarrow (or any arrow) inside my table. The table is as shown in the one below:

[image]

And I want to to be more like this:

[image]

And this is the code I have:

```
$\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{}%
\left\Downarrow
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
 {} & Aantal Zetels & Aantal Zetels           \\
 Strategie & Vrouwen & Mannen \\
\midrule
a &        10 &        0\\
b   &        4 &           6 \\
a    &        8 &  2\\
b    &        5 &           5 \\
a     &        7 &    3 \\
b  &        6 &          4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\right.
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{}$
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do the cells have to be in math mode? And what has to rotate?

Comment: This can be done with the package `tikzmark`. (and TikZ) https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark?lang=en

Answer (score 6):

Since your question is tagged [tikz-pgf](/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), I guess that a `\tikzmark` solution is fine.  You have to run LaTeX twice for the arrow to show up in the correct position.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tikz}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
  & Aantal Zetels & Aantal Zetels \\
  Strategie & Vrouwen & Mannen \\
  \midrule
  a \tikzmark{a} & 10 & 0 \\
  b & 4 & 6 \\
  a & 8 & 2 \\
  b & 5 & 5 \\
  a & 7 & 3 \\
  b \tikzmark{b} & 6 & 4 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[->] (a.center -| b.center) -- (b.center);
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You make this look sooo easy... :)

Comment: @AFeldman It is ;)

Comment: I am not sure about the advantage over the self defined command, but there are also a tikzmark package by the inventor.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, x11names]{article}
\usepackage{array, rotating, booktabs}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}%
  \begin{tabular}{lcrr}
    \toprule
      & & Aantal Zetels & Aantal Zetels \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{ Strategie} & Vrouwen & Mannen \\
    \midrule
    a & \pnode{B} & 10 & 0 \\
    b & & 4 & 6 \\
    a & & 8 & 2 \\
    b & & 5 & 5 \\
    a & & 7 & 3 \\
    b & \Rnode{E} & 6 & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
    \ncline[arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, offset=-6pt]{B}{E}
  \end{tabular}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]